Detecting ContentEditable Elements in ZenDesk
I am trying to write macros for work inside ZenDesk.
Capturing content from Slack & relaying it into RichContainers / ContentEditable.
I cannot for the life of me figure out how my extension can detect the contentEditable.
It works virtually on every other site / text box / element.
Detection of HTML Works. Parsing the JSON works. Formatting everything.Just doesnt work inside a richcontainer / content editable in ZenDesk.
I have enabled all urls on manifest and try to detect all elements as well.
Action
//macroName ' ' (space to activate/execute the macro)
Insert Macro inside contentEditable
// Function to handle input for potential macros
function handleGlobalInputFunction(event) {
    let target = event.target;  // Directly use the event's target element
    let value = target.textContent || target.value || ""; // Handle different types of editable elements

    // Perform macro replacement if the space was pressed and there's a potential macro
    if (event.data === ' ' && value.includes('//')) {
        let words = value.split(/\s+/);
        let lastWord = words[words.length - 2];

        if (lastWord.startsWith('//')) {
            let macroKey = lastWord.slice(2);
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({macro: macroKey}, (response) => {
                if (response.text) {
                    replaceText(target, lastWord, response.text);
                    placeCaretAtEnd(target);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

function replaceText(target, searchText, newText) {
    if (['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'].includes(target.tagName)) {
        target.value = target.value.replace(searchText + ' ', newText + ' ');
    } else if (target.isContentEditable) {
        target.textContent = target.textContent.replace(searchText + ' ', newText + ' ');
    }
}

// Utility function to place the caret at the end of an element's text
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        let range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        let sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
}

// Enhanced MutationObserver to handle dynamically added editable elements
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    mutations.forEach(mutation => {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
            if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && (node.isContentEditable || node.querySelector('[contenteditable="true"]'))) {
                if (node.isContentEditable) {
                    node.addEventListener('input', handleGlobalInputFunction);
                }
                node.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]').forEach(editable => {
                    editable.addEventListener('input', handleGlobalInputFunction);
                });
            }
        });

        if (mutation.type === "attributes" && mutation.attributeName === "contenteditable") {
            if (mutation.target.getAttribute("contenteditable") === "true") {
                mutation.target.addEventListener('input', handleGlobalInputFunction);
            }
        }
    });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ["contenteditable"]
});

// Attach to all input events on the document for newly dynamically added contenteditable elements
document.addEventListener('input', handleGlobalInputFunction, true);


I've tried changing the Mutation to detect contentEditable elements. Maybe also trying to detected Nested Contenteditable elements.

It may be inside an iframe. Use devtools element inspector to verify.
